# Activate-DeActivate feature on a remote spsite from a machine

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I want to disable a feature on a SPWeb from a remote machine. Is this possible through PowerShell or object model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your are not on SharePoint Box but still wants to activate/deactivate features on a `web` then we utilise `CSOM PowerShell` to do the job.

> Note: Before executing the below code, you must get the client object
>   model sdk installed on your client machine.

The snippet is `inspired` from this [Chris O'Brien: Using CSOM in PowerShell scripts with Office 365](http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2013/12/Using-CSOM-in-PowerShell-scripts-with-Office365.html)

```
Add-Type -Path 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll' -ErrorAction Stop
Add-Type -Path 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll'  -ErrorAction Stop

# Get credentials and set web url 
$credentials = Get-Credential 
$url = "http://SomeSite.sharepoint.com/YourWeb"

# connect/authenticate to SharePoint and get ClientContext object.. 
$clientContext = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($url) 
$clientContext.Credentials = $credentials 

[bool]$enable = $true
[bool]$force = $false

$FeatureId = [GUID]("xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx")

# working with the web-scoped Features
$webFeatures = $clientContext.Web.Features 
$clientContext.Load($webFeatures)
$clientContext.ExecuteQuery()

if ($enable)
{
    $webfeatures.Add($featureId, $force, [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FeatureDefinitionScope]::None)
}
else
{
    $webfeatures.Remove($featureId, $force)
}

try 
{
    $clientContext.ExecuteQuery()
    if ($enable)
    {
        Write-Host "Feature '$FeatureId' successfully activated.."
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Host "Feature '$FeatureId' successfully deactivated.."
    }
}
catch 
{
    Write-Error "An error occurred whilst activating/deactivating the Feature. Error detail: $($_)"
}
```

Comment: am getting the error : exception calling "ExecuteQuery" with "0" argument(s): "The remote server returned an error: (502) Bad Gateway."
At line:31 char:1
+ $clientContext.ExecuteQuery()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebException

Comment: @SaMoIPP p :  Do you have enough rights on the `SharePoint` machine? Or may be you can try to run `PowerShell` as administrator mode.

Comment: I already have full privileges in the sp dev machine.Using this id only, the installation of SP 2013 was performed, last year.

Comment: Did you ran the script in an administrator mode?

Comment: @SaMolPPp : I can confirm that using the code I can activate/deactivate subsite features runnig from remote machine. I tried this code for `Site Feed` feature for one of the subsite. I suspect other issue may be environment. Also open the `PowerShell ISE` in admin mode and I am the site collection admin.

Comment: Pranam Asad :-) .Its a perfect code worked like a charm. My issue was my SQL Server box was ran out of space.it has zero bytes.So definitely the script will fail.Now I deleted some .ldf files from  sql box and  reclaimed few MBs and worked.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25652/discussion-between-samolpp-p-and-asad-refai).

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the remoting-Function of Powershell to connect to a Sharpeoint-Powershell on the SharePoint-Server.

Otherwise you could write a Little application using the Client-Object-Model. Or of course you could include the SharePoint-Client-Object-Model in a Default-Powershell in your remote machine and do it that way

or you could do it using rest Services directly using the browser (however, this way you have to do a Little more to get the id of the requested Feature, but that won´t be hard to manage)
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/472cc1/sharepoint-2013-rest-series/